# MYSQL improve query performance when using OR

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a very simple MYSQL table with 2 columns and I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (col1 = '123' AND col2 = '456')
                       OR (col1 = '456' AND col2 = '123')
```

Col1 and col2 are a composite primary key: `PRIMARY KEY('col1','col2')`. Each of both is also a foreign key for primary key in another table

When I ran the EXPLAIN command for the above query i got the following:

```
id  select_type  table  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE       table  index   PRIMARY,col2    col2    8   NULL    1   Using where; Using index
```

The `type` in the above result is `index` which is very similar to `All` and so very likely to be slow on a large database. Is there a way to improve the above `select` command

Answer (score 1):

What about using a union?

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (col1 = '123' AND col2 = '456')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (col1 = '456' AND col2 = '123')`

Comment: I'd use UNION instead of UNION ALL

Comment: Yep good point @MannyCalavera !